# Agrupar buttons con MouseListener

Tags: java, botón, mouselistener

Tengo una serie de botones: `button_cancelar`, `button_limpiar`, `button_ok`.

Quisiera que al **pasar el entrar el ratón en el botón cambie de color** y al salir vuelva al estado inicial.

**¿Alguna manera de hacerlo en TODOS los botones de una vez?**

Con cada botón hago lo siguiente:

```
private void button_cancelarMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
  button_cancelar.setBackground(Color.decode("0xB4FF48"));
}

private void button_cancelarMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
  button_cancelar.setBackground(new Color(240, 240, 240));
}
```

¿Esto por cada botón o puedo sobreescribir `@Override` algún método de `MouseListener`?

```
public class Eliminar_cliente extends javax.swing.JDialog implements MouseListener{
  button_cancelar.addMouseListener(this);
  button_limpiar.addMouseListener(this);
  button_ok.addMouseListener(this);
}
```

**¿Qué métodos debería sobreescribir?**

Comment: Así tal cual hay que sobreescribir todos los métodos de `MouseListener` en especial `mouseEntered` y `mouseExited` dentro de ambos solo capturas el `JButton` que lanza el evento via `getSource()`

Answer (score 1):

Si hay una forma mas sencilla de asignar los `MouseListener` para cada uno de los botones.

Podrías definir cada uno de los metodos de la interfaz `MouseListener`, en este caso usando `mouseExited` y `mouseEntered`, para este caso en especifico.

Mediante el método `getSource()` puedes obtener el objeto que ha emitido el evento de forma que puedas hacer el cambio ahí.

```
public class MainClass {
  MouseListener listener = new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
      if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
        // ...de forma general (en caso que quieras el mismo color para todos
        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
        btn.setBackground(Color.decode("0xB4FF48"));

        // ...de forma especifica
        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
        if (btn.equals(btnCancelar)) {
          // do something...
        } else if (btn.equals(otherButton)){
          // do something...
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
      // de manera analoga
      if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
        btn.setBackground(new Color(240, 240, 240));
      }
    }
  };
```

Luego con una función de cantidad de parámetros variables puedes asignarles el *listener* a cada uno de ellos.

```
public void setButtonsListener(JButton... buttons) {    
  for (JButton btn: buttons)
    btn.addMouseListener(listener);
  }

  public void init() {
    // this (buttonsArray)
    setButtonsListener(buttonsArray);

    // or that (recibe n cantidad de elementos JButton en este caso)
    setButtonsListener(btnCancelar, btnBorrar, btnGuardar);
  }
}
```

De esta forma puedes definir el *listener* y dárselo a cada uno de ellos según sea el caso o alternativa que deseas seguir. Espero haberte ayudado :)